# how to sum all of the count items in xquery

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql, xquery-3.0, xquery-update, xquery-3.1

```
My problem is i want to display the count of all genre that is equals to actions
```

`

```
<videos genre="action" count="{
 for $videos in doc("videos.xml")/result/videos/video
 let $count := 0
  
  where $videos/genre ="action" 

 return count($videos/genre)
}"
```

`

``
but my result is this

the count is=1 1 1 i want the answer is equal to 3

```
im expecting a result that is 
<videos genre="action" count="3"><video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making it a bit too complicated; try something like:

```
<videos genre="action" count="{
count(doc("videos.xml")//video[.//genre[.="action"]])
}"/>
```

or, depending on the struture of you actual videos file, you can use instead

```
count(//video[.//.="action"])
```

Those should get you your expected output.

Comment: @AzilSorveto Glad it worked for you! If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer, please.